# Search jpeg files using python

Tags: python, search, file

My requirement is to search for jpeg images files in a directory using python script and list the file names. Can anyone help me on how to identify jpeg images files.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: By "identify", do you just mean files with a ".jpg" and ".jpeg" extension, or do you mean to actually look at the file contents and check whether it's a valid JPEG image?

Comment: No i just want to search using the file extension.

Answer (score 10):

If you need to search a single folder non-recursively you can simply do

```
>>> import glob
>>> glob.glob("D:\\bluetooth\*.jpg")
['D:\\bluetooth\\Image1475.jpg',  'D:\\bluetooth\\Image1514.jpg']
```

Read more about [glob](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html) here, you use do unix like wildcard searches e.g.

```
>>> import glob
>>> glob.glob('./[0-9].*')
['./1.gif', './2.txt']
>>> glob.glob('*.gif')
['1.gif', 'card.gif']
>>> glob.glob('?.gif')
['1.gif']
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to scan subfolders:

```
import os

for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(DIRECTORY):
    for file in files:
        if os.path.splitext(file)[1].lower() in ('.jpg', '.jpeg'):
             print os.path.join(root, file)
```

Otherwise, using one of the other glob functions in the other answers, or this:

```
import os

for f in os.listdir(DIRECTORY):
    if os.path.splitext(f)[1].lower() in ('.jpg', '.jpeg'):
        print os.path.join(DIRECTORY, f)
```

should work OK.

Comment: `splitext` returns the extension with a dot, so you want `in ('.jpg', '.jpeg')`.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I've updated it, thanks for correcting me :-)

Comment: But I don't want to find files in the subdirectories.

Comment: OK, I've updated the answer to include only scanning a single folder.

Comment: What is the value of root, subdirs at the first iteration? And where is the use of subdirs?

Comment: Using list comprehension: file_list = [f for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(folder_data) for f in files if  f.endswith('.jpg') or f.endswith('.jpeg')]

Comment: rather than using os.path.splitext(file)[1] I would recommend to use 'endswith'

Answer (score 2):

Use the `magic` module to get the MIME type, and look for `image/jpeg`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
path=os.path.join("/home","mypath","to_search")
for r,d,f in os.walk(path):
     for files in f:
           if files[-3:].lower()=='jpg' of files[-4:].lower() =="jpeg":
                print "found: ",os.path.join(r,files)
```

Comment: I find that the `str.endswith()` is easier to read.
@Nims: consider validating this answer, or at least upvoting it.

Comment: I suggest `if os.path.splitext(files)[1] in ('.jpg', '.jpeg'):`, otherwise a file named `imnotajpeg` would be processed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to determine the image format by file contents, you can use the [Python Imaging Library](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/):

```
import Image
try:
    img = Image.open('maybe_jpeg_file')
    print img.format # Will return 'JPEG' for JPEG files.
except IOError:
    print "Not an image file or unreadable."
```